# Compiling C Program in VS code using Code runner

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code, compiler-construction, vscode-code-runner

I have written a simple c program and given it a name of **program**
When The code is made to run using code runner extension it uses this kind of statement

```
PS C:\Users\user_name> cd "c:\Users\user_name\Desktop\" ; if ($?) { gcc program.c -o program } ; if ($?) { .\program }
```

In this i could understand ( gcc program.c -o program ) but
what does `if ($?) and if($?) {.\program }` mean ?

Comment: I would recommend adding more switches: `-Wall -Werror` to the gcc command line!

Comment: In many environments, `$?` refers to the exit status of the last execution. I guess that `if ($?)` means "if the last step succeeded".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if($?) means if the previous step is successful

```
PS C:\Users\user_name> cd "c:\Users\user_name\Desktop\" ; if ($?) { gcc program.c -o program } ;
```

here if ($?) means if there exists a file named program.c then compile using the command

```
gcc program.c -o program
```

so does the next line,

```
if ($?) { .\program }
```

if the executable file is succesfully created then run the executable file using `.\program` command